# Group By showing duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I'm trying to select rows for this meetings application we're doing. 
Meetings have one or more Agenda Items, these Agenda Items have an EventNumber (which is 0 if no event is linked, or an integer if there is)

I want to select only one row per meeting, but I get more than one if for the same meeting we have maybe an Agenda item with a EventNumber of 0, and one different than 0. Just need the know if for that whole meeting, at least one of the AgendaItems has an EventNumber different than zero.

The query is almost there. It works when a meeting has only AgendaItems with EventNumbers = 0, but it brings back duplicates when a meeting has a mix of both.

Tried adding a HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 after the Grouping, or saying MAX(MeetingAgendaItem.EventNumber), and applying the DISTNCT keyword after the SELECt.

```sql
SELECT
    Meeting.Id, 
    Meeting.Location, 
    Meeting.Name, 
    MeetingAgendaItem.EventNumber,
    Meeting.StartDate,
    Meeting.EndDate

FROM ((Meeting 
    LEFT JOIN MeetingInvitees ON (Meeting.Id = MeetingInvitees.MeetingId))
    LEFT JOIN MeetingAgendaItem ON (Meeting.Id = MeetingAgendaItem.MeetingId))

GROUP BY Meeting.Id, Meeting.Location, Meeting.Name, MeetingAgendaItem.EventNumber, Meeting.StartDate, Meeting.EndDate

ORDER BY Meeting.Id
```

```
Id  Location Name                   Meeting Name        EventNumber          StartDate              EndDate
19  Pont des Charrettes, 30700, FR  Meeting Generated   0                    29-06-2019 00:00:00    29-06-2019 23:59:59
19  Pont des Charrettes, 30700, FR  Meeting Generated   8747                 29-06-2019 00:00:00    29-06-2019 23:59:59
```

Comment: Tag appropriate database. Add some sample data and expected output from them.

Comment: You got two rows back. Which one would YOU rather keep and why? Given this result set you've shared here a `max(MeetingAdendaItem.EventNumber)` while removing `MeetingAgendaItem.EventNumber` from the `GROUP BY` would definitely only return one record.

Comment: As long as you group by EventNumber and there can be more than one EventNumber per meeting, you will get multiple results for the same meeting. Removing the EventNumber from the select should work fine, combined with a condition on EventNumber

Comment: And really... looking at this query. WHY would you even bother joining in the attendees table. It's not used here at all. For that matter why even join in the Agenda Item table too? It seems superfluous to grab a random (or max) `EventNumber` in this result set. `SELECT * FROM Meeting ORDER BY id` would make the most sense here.

Comment: @JNevill seems we were typing at the same time...

Comment: Lastly, depending on which RDBMS product you are using, one possible reasonable result here with those `EventNumbers` would be to do a `Group_Concat()` or `ListAgg()` or whatever similar feature your RDBMS supports. That way that one record would have a comma separated list of all `EventNumbers` for that one Meeting ID.

Comment: @marianopicco . . . Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Trying to answer some of the questions: SQL is SQL-Server. Attendees is there because I need to search within them, but I removed the WHERE clauses altogether not to make it confusing; the result is the same.
As far as to which row I want to keep, I just want to know if for this Meeting, there's at least one AgendaItem which includes an Event Number <> 0. So, I'd want to keep the one with the actual number, but no need to keep the number itself, could be a true or false flag.

Comment: There is no useful purpose to parenthesizing the joins - the same result will naturally be returned without them and their removal will make reading and understanding the query easier. You should always strive to make your code easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by taking `MAX(MeetingAgendaItem.EventNumber)` and removing it from the `GROUP BY`. This will give you the largest `EventNumber` associated with the Agenda item (or 0 if they are all 0), which seems to meet the criteria in your question. Change your query to this:

```
SELECT
    Meeting.Id, 
    Meeting.Location, 
    Meeting.Name, 
    MAX(MeetingAgendaItem.EventNumber),
    Meeting.StartDate,
    Meeting.EndDate

FROM ((Meeting 
    LEFT JOIN MeetingInvitees ON (Meeting.Id = MeetingInvitees.MeetingId))
    LEFT JOIN MeetingAgendaItem ON (Meeting.Id = MeetingAgendaItem.MeetingId))

GROUP BY Meeting.Id, Meeting.Location, Meeting.Name, Meeting.StartDate, Meeting.EndDate

ORDER BY Meeting.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select * from (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Meeting.Id,Meeting.Location,Meeting.Name, Meeting.StartDate,Meeting.EndDate order by Meeting.Location) rn,
    Meeting.Id, 
    Meeting.Location, 
    Meeting.Name, 
    MeetingAgendaItem.EventNumber,
    Meeting.StartDate,
    Meeting.EndDate

FROM ((Meeting 
    LEFT JOIN MeetingInvitees ON (Meeting.Id = MeetingInvitees.MeetingId))
    LEFT JOIN MeetingAgendaItem ON (Meeting.Id = MeetingAgendaItem.MeetingId))

GROUP BY Meeting.Id, Meeting.Location, Meeting.Name, MeetingAgendaItem.EventNumber, Meeting.StartDate, Meeting.EndDate

ORDER BY Meeting.Id
) t where rn=1
```

Comment: Why order by `Meeting.Location` in your window function? The more likely candidate would be one of the columns in the result set that is distinct like `EventNumber` but then a simple `Min(EventNumber)` would accomplish the same thing without the expensive windowing step.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add "MeetingAgendaItem.EventNumber > 0" criteria on your join as well:

```
SELECT
Meeting.Id, 
Meeting.Location, 
Meeting.Name, 
MeetingAgendaItem.EventNumber,
Meeting.StartDate,
Meeting.EndDate

FROM ((Meeting 
LEFT JOIN MeetingInvitees ON (Meeting.Id = MeetingInvitees.MeetingId))
LEFT JOIN MeetingAgendaItem ON (Meeting.Id = MeetingAgendaItem.MeetingId AND MeetingAgendaItem.EventNumber > 0 ))

GROUP BY Meeting.Id, Meeting.Location, Meeting.Name, MeetingAgendaItem.EventNumber, 
Meeting.StartDate, Meeting.EndDate

ORDER BY Meeting.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT m.*
       (SELECT MAX(mai.EventNumber)
        FROM MeetingAgendaItem mai
        WHERE m.Id = mai.MeetingId
       ) as max_EventNumber          
FROM Meeting m
ORDER BY m.Id;
```

Notes:

- You are not using the invitees table, so I removed it.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The invitees table is one of the causes of duplicates.  You want one row per meeting so no outer `GROUP BY` is needed.
- This should be much more efficient than your version, because it eliminates unneeded duplicate records and the outer `group by`.